# error in following c code

Tags: c

*Note: The question has been edited to make the problem go away.*

I have written this code to reverse an array using functions. But there is an error in line 24 saying ' ) expected'. I have read it again and again but i couldn't find the error. Can anybody please reveal it and tell me how to remove it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define max 5

/*function prototype*/
void reverse(int[],int);

void main()
{
    int arr[max]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int i,j;
    clrscr();
    printf("the list before reversing:\n");
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    reverse(arr,max);
    printf("\n the list after reversing:\n");
    for(i=0;i<max;i++)
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    getch();
}

/*function for reversing elements of array*/
void reverse(int num[],int max)
{
     int i,j,temp;
     for(i=0,j=max-1;i<max/2;i++,j--)
     {
            temp=num[i];
        num[i]=num[j];
        num[j]=temp;
     }
}
```

Comment: Missing `for` ?!

Comment: this is a really basic problem for which searching for a solution here is quite overkill.

Comment: @Sushil - Editing the question to make the problem go away is **really** impolite to us reading it afterwards!

Comment: @Bo Persson: I think you are wrong: the (actual) problem is still there: having a macro named "max" (="5") and having a parameter named "max" too. The missing "for" was not the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

`max` is defined as a macro. So after preprocessing it becomes

```
void reverse(int num[],int 5)
```

Which is not valid and you are getting `' ) expected'`. If `max` is constant then there is no need to pass it as a parameter. And also you have a missing `for` in the function.

Comment: but the book i m referring to is passing the macro max as a parameter. So is it against the syntax of c.?

Comment: Not sure what is in the book. f(int 5) is not a valid syntax. May be you misunderstood something. You should check with the original code present in the book. May be it is not using macro in function definition, only using when calling the function.

Comment: oops sorry i did not see your answer before and i posted my answer.I agree with your Answer taskinoor.Your right so let me make it upvote lol

Comment: @Sushil and taskinoor: maybe the code in the book used UPPER CASE for the macro ("MAX"; which is common so it doesn't get confused with variables/parameters having the same name "max"), but Sushi didn't copy the code with same case letters?

Comment: @Curd, may be. We can't be sure without seeing the actual code in the book.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing the `for` keyword in the loop header in `reverse()`.

Comment: no the for header is there... i missed it while copying code here...

Comment: That might be true, but it doesn't explain the error in line 24.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Ok, ok my first answer was stupid...
(Answered without thinking enough)

Now I got it:

The problem is

```
#define max 5
```

Later `max` (=5) is used as a parameter!

Comment: HEY EVERYONE IT IS WORKING FINE AFTER I HAVE REMOVED THE MACRO FROM PARAMETER AND USED IT DIRECTLY. THANKS EVERYONE. YOU JUST SAVED A NOVICE PROGRAMMER. :)

Comment: @Sushi: If my (last) answer helped to solve your problem, feel free to upvote it ;-)